# Akka Streams: Fan-out operator with custom logic

Tags: akka-stream

I am looking for an Akka Streams operator that would allow me to split a stream based on custom logic. The set of messages that I am expecting is known in advance so there is no need for dynamic scaling of downstream consumers.

In the earlier versions of the library - when it was still labeled experimental - there was a `FlexiRoute` operator. I saw that at some point it accumulated a lot of cruft and was subsequently removed in favor of `GraphStage`.

Nowadays there are operators like `Balance` and `Partition` that come close to what I need. `Balance` requires me to duplicate logic per consumer. `Partition` works only for two outputs and I need to have N. I could make it happen with a `Partition` per message type but that seems hacky.

Is building a custom solution the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition is what you need. It works for N rather than only 2 outputs. Read https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Partition.html for API, read https://blog.colinbreck.com/partitioning-akka-streams-to-maximize-throughput/#partition for example.

A snapshot of the API doc:

```scala
new Partition(outputPorts: Int, partitioner: (T) ⇒ Int, eagerCancel: Boolean)
```

A snapshot of the example:

```scala
val flow = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val workerCount = 4

  val partition = b.add(Partition[Int](workerCount, _ % workerCount))
  val merge = b.add(Merge[Int](workerCount))

  for (_ <- 1 to workerCount) {
    partition ~> Flow[Int].map(spin).async ~> merge
  }

  FlowShape(partition.in, merge.out)
})

Source(1 to 1000)
  .via(flow)
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: You are correct. The only thing one needs to keep in mind is that you need to introduce a function that consistently maps incoming types to a given partition number.